# How to UPDATE MySQL for each row from this code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update rows 'tracking', 'carrier', 'status' where is status 'Waiting for tracking'

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status = 'Waiting for tracking'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $tracking = $row['tracking'];
        $carrier = $row['carrier'];
        $link = $row['link'];

        // get DOM from URL or file
        $html = file_get_html($link);

        // find td tags with data-qa=shipment-tracking-number
        foreach($html->find('td[data-qa=shipment-tracking-number]') as $tracking)
            $tracking = $tracking->plaintext;

        // find td tags with data-qa=shipment-carrier
        foreach($html->find('td[data-qa=shipment-carrier]') as $carrier)
            $carrier = $carrier->plaintext;

        if(isset($tracking)) {
            $tracking = "UPDATE orders SET tracking = '$tracking' WHERE id = '$id'";
            $tracking_result = $mysqli->query($tracking);

            if($mysqli->query($tracking_result) === true) {
                $pendnig = "UPDATE orders SET status = 'Pending' WHERE id = '$id'";
                $pending_result = $mysqli->query($pending);
            }
        }

        if(isset($carrier)) {
            $carrier = "UPDATE orders SET carrier = '$carrier' WHERE id = '$id'";
            $carrier_result = $mysqli->query($carrier);
        }
    }
}
```

When execute file, update me only 'tracking' and 'carrier' not update status as 'Pending' and only for first row, not for other.

Comment: I guess you should fix that variable typo and then try again: "$pendig" vs. "query($pending)".

Comment: @HappyAnt yes you are right. Changed, but same result.

Comment: If this is reflecting the actual code on your server, it won't run because the variable names still don't match...

Comment: I found in MySQL under 'link' I have blank space, so now can update all rows, but can't update 'status' as Pending.

Comment: use `prepared statements to avoid SQL injection. And why do you use 3 UPDATE statements to update the same row?

Comment: @nacho this file will execute automatically on every few hours, you think I need to have prepared statements for this? 

3 UPDATE used for testing, it will be in one update now.

Comment: Yes, you allways need prepared statements. It takes the same time and the same efort and avoids actual and future problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if update query get succeed as below:

```
if($tracking_result) {
    $pendnig = "UPDATE orders SET status = 'Pending' WHERE id = '$id'";
    $pending_result = $mysqli->query($pending);
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes, this help. I use

if($tracking_result === true) {
    echo "success";
       $pendnig = "UPDATE orders SET status = 'Pending' WHERE id = '$id'";
       $pending_result = $mysqli->query($pendnig);
   }

Comment: Pleasure it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it with new code.

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status = 'Waiting for tracking'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $tracking = $row['tracking'];
        $carrier = $row['carrier'];
        $link = $row['link'];

        // get DOM from URL or file
        $html = file_get_html($link);

        // find td tags with data-qa=shipment-tracking-number
        foreach($html->find('td[data-qa=shipment-tracking-number]') as $tracking)
            $tracking = $tracking->plaintext;

        // find td tags with data-qa=shipment-carrier
        foreach($html->find('td[data-qa=shipment-carrier]') as $carrier)
            $carrier = $carrier->plaintext;

        if(isset($tracking)) {
            $tracking = "UPDATE orders SET tracking = '$tracking' WHERE id = '$id'";
            $tracking_result = $mysqli->query($tracking);

            if($tracking_result === true) {
                $pendnig = "UPDATE orders SET status = 'Pending' WHERE id = '$id'";
                $pending_result = $mysqli->query($pendnig);
            }
        }

        if(isset($carrier)) {
            $carrier = "UPDATE orders SET carrier = '$carrier' WHERE id = '$id'";
            $carrier_result = $mysqli->query($carrier);
        }

        // clean up memory
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);
    }
}
```